# Unable to authenticate on Matrix Routing v8 HereMaps API

Tags: here-api, heremaps

We are new to here maps and are trying (POC) for distance matrix API. We have setup our account and linked all services. Still we are getting

```
{
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "error_description": "These credentials do not authorize access"
}
```

We have tried both apiKey and Bearer token authentication. Please guide us on how to proceed further.
Our sample request:

```
curl --location 'https://matrix.router.hereapi.com/v8/matrix?async=false&apiKey={our_api_key}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "origins": [
        {"lat": 52.52103, "lng": 13.41268},
        {"lat": 52.51628, "lng": 13.37771},
        {"lat": 52.47342, "lng": 13.40357}
    ],
    "regionDefinition": {
        "type": "autoCircle"
    },
    "matrixAttributes": ["distances"]
}
'
```